# error during sending email with codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, email

Email is not sent by codeigniter.please check and identify the erros.
MY controller code is:

```
$config = Array(
  'protocol' => 'smtp',
  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
  'smtp_port' => 465,
  'smtp_user' => 'bilalshabbir3210@gmail.com', // change it to yours
  'smtp_pass' => 'my pasword', // change it to yours
  'mailtype' => 'html',
  'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
  'wordwrap' => TRUE
);

        $message = '<h4>Email comessss</h4>';
        $this->load->library('email', $config);
      $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
      $this->email->from('bilalshabbir3210@gmail.com'); // change it to yours
      $this->email->to('bilalshabbir0909@gmail.com');// change it to yours
      $this->email->subject('Resume from JobsBuddy for your Job posting');
      $this->email->message($message);
      if($this->email->send())
     {
      echo 'Email sent.';
     }
     else
    {
     show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
```

And error comes: 
[]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9ENf.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error makes it appear that your code cannot contact the SMTP server you've told it to use. A quick google implies that the server should be smtp.gmail.com.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following settings, this work very well with google

```
$config = array(
    'protocol'      => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host'     => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'smtp_port'     => 465,
    'smtp_crypto'   => 'ssl',

    'smtp_timeout'  => '30',
    'smtp_user'     => 'your_mail@gmail.com',   // change it to yours
    'smtp_pass'     => 'your_gmail_password',   //  change it to yours
    'charset'       => 'iso-8859-1',
    'crlf'          => "\r\n",
    'newline'       => "\r\n",
    'mailtype'      => 'html',
    'wordwrap'      => TRUE
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);

$this->email->from('your_mail@gmail.com');      //  change it to yours
$list = array('destination_list@gmail.com');    //  change it to yours
$this->email->to($list);
$this->email->subject('This is an email test');

$message = '<h4>Email comessss</h4>';
$this->email->message($message);
if($this->email->send())
{
    echo 'Email sent.';
} else {
    show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
}
```