# mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, smtp

I am currently working on send mail in codeigniter below are details of smtp but I am getting error how to solve this issue some posts on stackoverflow asked to make some modifications in php.ini still getting same issue.

```
$config = Array(//for gmail Settings 
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_user' => 'xyz@gmail.com', // user details
                    'smtp_pass' => 'xyzxyz', // password
                    'mailtype' => 'html',
                    'charset' => 'iso-8859-1',
                    'wordwrap' => TRUE
                );




               $this->load->library('email', $config);
                $this->email->set_header('MIME-Version', '1.0; charset=utf-8');
                $this->email->set_header('Content-type', 'text/html');
                $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                 $this->email->from('xyz@gmail.com@gmail.com', 'xyz.com'); //sender's email

                $this->email->to($email); // change it to yours
                $this->email->subject('Password reset email');
                $message = "<h2>You have requested to reset password</h2>";
                $message .= "<a href='" . base_url('controller') . "/" . "methodname/" . $reset . "'> Click here to reset your password</a>";
                $this->email->message($message);
                $send = $this->email->send();
```

[image]

Comment: what changes you have made in php.ini

Comment: seems that email library is not initialized with provided configuration and are using config from `/application/config/email.php` file

Comment: take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622494/1841852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config helped me to solve my issue

```
$config = array(
                    'protocol' => 'smtp',
                    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'smtp_port' => 465,
                    'smtp_crypto' => 'ssl',
                    'smtp_timeout' => '30',
                    'smtp_user' => 'xyz@gmail.com', //  your smtp user
                    'smtp_pass' => 'xyzxyz', //  your smtp password
                    'wordwrap' => TRUE
                );
```